# Android ViewModel & Dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

What's wrong with this approach, I see a lot of people doing custom work for getting ViewModel to work with dagger, but why doesn't this solution I have work?

```
class MyActivity {
   @inject lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

   oncreate() {
                DaggerLoginComponent
        .builder()
        .appComponent(App.component)
        .loginModule(MyModule(this))
        .build()
        .inject(this)
   }
}

@Module
class MyActivityModule(prival val activity: MyActivity) {
   @provides
   fun provideViewModel(dep1: Dependency, dep2: Dependency) =
       ViewModelProviders.of(activity, this.viewModeFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}

class MyViewModel {
    init(dep1: Dependency, dep2: Dependency) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Where did `viewModeFactory` come from, what does it do? What is the scope of the component? When do you pass the Activity to the component?

Comment: **What's wrong with this approach**, what is the advantage of your approach so?

Comment: There is no advantage to my approach, this is the standard way of using dagger, I'm trying to see why it doesn't work when it comes to ViewModels due to different lifecycle than the activity

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any errors?